# How to iterate and print text with 2 columns in lua?

Tags: lua

For demonstration, I got the following text file called output.txt which contains this simple data:

```
/etc/csf/csf.deny Hello this is abc
/var/lib/csf/csf.tempip Hello this is CSF
/var/lib/csf/csf.tempban That is nice you got tempban here!
/root/blocked_ips.txt blocked ip is not great
```

I want to store the first column as var1 and the rest of the column as var2. As I'm familiar with bash, I can achieve this with the following code in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

output="output.txt"
var1=$(awk '{ print $1 }' $output)
var2=$(awk '{$1=""; $0=$0; $1=$1; print}' $output)

while read -r var1 var2; do
    echo "Var1: $var1 , Var2: $var2"
    # -- Now I can use var1 and var2 to do something else in this loop
done <"$output"
```

the output for this bash script:

```
[root]# ./test
Var1: /etc/csf/csf.deny , Var2: Hello this is abc
Var1: /var/lib/csf/csf.tempip , Var2: Hello this is CSF
Var1: /var/lib/csf/csf.tempban , Var2: That is nice you got tempban here!
Var1: /root/blocked_ips.txt , Var2: blocked ip is not great
```

I can use `popen` in lua script (which a wrapper from bash script) to achieve this but is there a lua native implementation?

Comment: Actually I tried to use popen with lua using the same bash script. it works. but I only want lua implementation as I'm very new to lua.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for line in io.lines"output.txt" do
   local var1, var2 = line:match"(%S*)%s*(.*)"
   print(var1)
   print(var2)
end
```